# Why put the value in Entry instead of ThreadLocal?

Tags: java, multithreading

Thread use a threadLocals which type is ThreadLocalMap to store thread-local variables.And ThreadLocalMap use an array to store Entry.Some source codes are displayed as:

```
static class Entry extends WeakReference<ThreadLocal<?>> {
            /** The value associated with this ThreadLocal. */
            Object value;

            Entry(ThreadLocal<?> k, Object v) {
                super(k);
                value = v;
            }
        }
```

If we put the value in ThreadLocal class, the value will be recycled by gc when it not be needed.Isn't it be more suitable than in Entry?
Any one can help me?
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Some context please. What' Entry?

Comment: *puts the value in ThreadLocal,the value will be recycled by gc whiling it working* No, it will GC it once its unreachable, meaning, when the specific owner thread dies. That's not "while working" state, but "finished"

Comment: It's a weak reference,it need not waiting for specific owner thread dies.It will be expunged    while the gc works next time.

Comment: The weak references are just for the map's keys. The value cannot be recycled because there is a strong reference connected from the currentthread. *Only after the current thread ends, the strong reference is broken, the current thread, Map and value will be recycled by GC.*

Comment: Yes,that's the point.
The key is a thread local variable, and the value is a object which may be anything.If we put the object in thread local class, then the value become parts of key.It will be recycled with the key!Isn't it more suitable?

Answer (score 1):

### Assumptions

1. The questions seems to be asking why java uses Map.Entry store ThreadLocal context?

### Possible answer

> Each thread holds an implicit reference to its copy of a thread-local variable as long as the thread is alive and the ThreadLocal instance is accessible; after a thread goes away, all of its copies of thread-local instances are subject to garbage collection (unless other references to these copies exist).

Ref: [JavaDoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/ThreadLocal.html)

If the concern about ThreadLocal.ThreadLocalMap.WeakReference,

> ```
>    ThreadLocalMap is a customized hash map suitable only for
>
>    maintaining thread local values. No operations are exported
>   
>    outside of the ThreadLocal class. The class is package private to
>    
>    allow declaration of fields in class Thread.  To help deal with
>    
>    very large and long-lived usages, the hash table entries use
>    
>    WeakReferences for keys. However, since reference queues are not
>    
>    used, stale entries are guaranteed to be removed only when
>    
>    the table starts running out of space.
> ```

Ref: Source Code of ThreadLocal

WeakReference is used only to cleanup when the actual thread is not reachable(candidate for GC)

### Alternate Scenario

1. A pool of threads are shared across multiple requests
2. Each request is processed by multiple classes
3. Each request runs in a thread(a request can also span multiple threads, but we consider the simple case)
4. The request sets some custom values in the `ThreadLocal` object
5. This `ThreadLocal` is owned by the actual thread in the pool
6. Now before completing the request, the business logic of the thread should ensure to clear an state added to `ThreadLocal` object
7. Otherwise, this data will exist in `ThreadLocal` object for the lifetime of the thread.
8. If the state added to the `ThreadLocal` was adding a Map or some list, then it will result in leak(stale data with active reference from threadlocal)

### Sample Code

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.concurrent.ExecutorService;
import java.util.concurrent.Executors;
import java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit;

public class ThreadLocalTest {

    static class MyThreadLocalManager {
        // this risky as List is stored in ThreadLocal.
        private static ThreadLocal<List<String>> state = ThreadLocal.withInitial(() -> new ArrayList<>());

        public void store(final String  value) {
            // careful as this is appending to thread state that can be shared by multiple business processes
            state.get().add(value);
        }

        public String getLastValue() {
            List<String> current = state.get();
            if (current.size() > 0) {
                return current.get(current.size() - 1);
            }
            return null;
        }

        public void reset() {
            // cleaning the threadlocal state of the thread in execution
            state.get().clear();
        }

        @Override
        public String toString() {
            return "MyThreadLocalManager{" +
                "state=" + state.get().toString() +
                "}";
        }
    }

    static class BusinessService {
        private static final MyThreadLocalManager threadLocalManager = new MyThreadLocalManager();

        public void store(String value) {
            threadLocalManager.store(value);
        }

        public void print() {
            System.out.println(threadLocalManager.getLastValue());
            System.out.println(threadLocalManager.toString());
        }

        public void begin() {
            threadLocalManager.reset();
        }

        public void complete() {
            // cleaning the threadlocal state
            threadLocalManager.reset();
        }
    }

    static void improperUsage() throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            final String key = String.valueOf(i);
            final String value = String.valueOf(100 + i);
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                // scope of business service entity only this run method
                BusinessService businessService = new BusinessService();
                businessService.store(value);
                businessService.print();
                // even though the business object goes out of scope,
                // the value it persisted in ThreadLocal will still be alive
                // and is a strong reference is our ThreadLocal list
                // this list will be there until the thread is there
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
    }

    static void properUsage() throws Exception {
        ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(2);
        for (int i = 11; i < 15; i++) {
            final String key = String.valueOf(i);
            final String value = String.valueOf(100 + i);
            executorService.submit(() -> {
                // scope of business service entity only this run method
                BusinessService businessService = new BusinessService();
                businessService.begin();
                businessService.store(value);
                businessService.print();
                // cleaning the threadlocal state
                businessService.complete();
            });
        }
        executorService.shutdown();
        executorService.awaitTermination(5, TimeUnit.SECONDS);

    }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("Started Improper Usage");
        improperUsage();
        System.out.println("Completed Improper Usage");

        // print line separator
        System.out.println(new String(new char[25]).replace("", "-"));

        System.out.println("Started Proper Usage");
        properUsage();
        System.out.println("Completed Proper Usage");
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your response.
My English is not well.So May be I cannot express my thought suitable.
I think if we store the value in ThreadLocal class, the value will be recycled by gc automatically.But now the value is stored in entry.It must be cleaned manually.

Comment: @cuijr, Are you referring about storing the value in ThreadLocal or your custom Map. If you are planning to use your custom map, then you need to clean from your Map. If you referring to `ThreadLocal` in some server threads or executor service or fork join pool, then please take care about storing any collections(key-values pairs or appending to lists) across different executions of business login over time. Since the same(mostly) pool of threads will be used, care must be taken to clean up business logic specific storage. Else it will lead to memory leak and will result in OOM

Comment: @cuijr please check the updated answer